# How can I split a splited field in AWK?

Tags: sql, unix, awk, sql-insert, ksh

I'm developing a script that has to take a text file with the format:
field1@field2@20200101133030@field4
and I need to convert it into a sql insert command. Well. The third field is a date. I have a script that converts the date into to_date('2020/01/01:13:30:30', 'yyyy/mm/dd:hh24:mi:ss'),

```
funcion(){
        echo $1 | nawk -v s1="\047" -v firstPart="to_date(" -v lastPart="yyyy/mm/dd:hh24:mi:ss" '
                {
                        print firstPart s1 substr($0,1,4) "/" substr($0,5,2) "/" substr($0,7,2)":"\
                        substr($0,9,2)":"substr($0,11,2)":"substr($0,13,2) s1 ", " s1\
                        lastPart s1 ")"
                }'
}
```

And I have another script that splits the whole line into a insert command:

```
createInsert(){
        echo $1 | awk -F'@' '{
        printf "INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (\x27%s\x27,\x27%s\x27,\x27%s\x27,\x27%s\x27,\x27%s\x27,\x27%s\x27,\x27%s\x27);",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7;print ""
        }'
}
```

That works OK. Output:

```
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ('0000000','D00','20200901131010','20200917133115','20200917142400','20200923120401','N');
```

My issue is that I need to convert the $3, $4 and $5 fields using the function below. But I think that awk doesn't allow to call another function like

```
createInsert(){
        echo $1 | awk -F'@' '{
        printf "INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (\x27%s\x27,\x27%s\x27,\x27%s\x27,\x27%s\x27,\x27%s\x27,\x27%s\x27,\x27%s\x27);",$1,$2,**$(funcion $3)**,$4,$5,$6,$7;print ""
        }'
}
```

Is there any form to create One single method that splits the fields $3, 4 and 5 and does the same that the other functions does (create it into a toDate function)

Thank you, hope your answers.

SUMMARY:
Input:

```
`"0000000@D01@000000@20200910103010@20200910111111@20200910100403@N@"`
```

Output:

```
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ('0000000','D01','000000','to_date('2020/09/10:10:30:10', 'yyyy/mm/dd:hh24:mi:ss')',''to_date('2020/09/11:11:11:11', 'yyyy/mm/dd:hh24:mi:ss')','to_date('2020/10/10:04:03', 'yyyy/mm/dd:hh24:mi:ss')','N');
```

Comment: Could you please post sample of input and expected output in your question for better understanding of question here.

Comment: Input: "0000000@D01@000000@20200910103010@20200910111111@20200910100403@N@"
Output:INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ('7243176','D01','000000','to_date('2020/09/10:10:30:10', 'yyyy/mm/dd:hh24:mi:ss')',''to_date('2020/09/11:11:11:11', 'yyyy/mm/dd:hh24:mi:ss')','to_date('2020/10/10:04:03', 'yyyy/mm/dd:hh24:mi:ss')','N');

Comment: Could you please post this in your question as comments are not meant to show samples.

Comment: @revindersingh13 sure

Comment: You can call functions that are written within awk from awk itself. Looks like your function is actually awk script and so just move the function from outside of awk to inside of it.

Comment: @Vazzattacc, Could you please explain how timings `2020/10/10:04:03` is coming in output it doesn't appear in input I believe.

Comment: Its because i was changing the output because those are real data and i didn't change it well (i invented them xD)

Comment: @RamanSailopal Could you put an example of the syntax of it please?
Thank you for your comment!

Comment: @Vazzattacc, is this value `7243176` hard coded or in samples because if values are not clear then we can't create correct command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, this is completely based on shown samples of OP in GNU `awk`. In case your field numbers are different than shown samples then try changing field numbers in solution and it should work for you, I also considered that your shown value `7243176` we need to hardcode if that's not the case then you could put respective field number there to get it.

```
awk -v s1="'" '
BEGIN{
  FS="@"
  OFS="\047, \047"
}
{
  print "INSERT INTO myTable VALUES(\0477243176",$2,$1,\
  "to_date(\047" substr($4,1,4)"/"substr($4,5,2)"/"\
  substr($4,7,2)":"substr($4,9,2)":"substr($4,11,2)":"\
  substr($4,13,2),"yyyy/mm/dd:hh24:mi:ss\047)","\
  to_date(\047" substr($5,1,4)"/"substr($5,5,2)"/"\
  substr($5,7,2)":"substr($5,9,2)":"substr($5,11,2)\
  ":"substr($5,13,2),"yyyy/mm/dd:hh24:mi:ss\047)\
  " ",\047N\047)"
}
'  Input_file
```

Also considering that `"` is not part of your sample input in case it is then you could use `sub` function to substitute it inside main block of `awk` program.